# How do I remove this doorknob?

Tags: doors, lock, doorknob

We live in a townhouse built in the 40s ... probably renovated in the 50s ...

I want to replace this doorknob with one that has a key lock.

I can't figure out how to remove it!

I was able to unscrew the ring that holds the large plate against the door, but I don't see how to remove the knob / assembly.

Anyone seen anything like this?

There are no holes/screws on the actual knob/handle part. There's some strange looking hardware behind the plate.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! It's a "Sargent". Found the answer here
http://youtu.be/VyzTw5l-xhs

Thank you, Internet!