# How can I remove a Yale doorknob installed with the latch at the incorrect length?

Tags: doors, doorknob

I forgot to adjust the length before placing the inside knob. Now the latch wont go all the way in. And I cant see the notch release because the door knob is too close to the door

[image]

For example only (the 'tab' in question for the "notch release", which is not accessible): https://www.pinterest.com/pin/272045633715850019/

[image]

Comment: Length of what? What do the instructions say? Why not simply remove the whole thing and start over, adjusting the length properly at the right time?

Comment: I tried to edit your title into a coherent question. Please revise further as needed. Also revise your post, which isn't clear. What "notch release"? Why can't you remove the interior knob?

Comment: +1 for including a picture. -1 for it being dark and not giving a hint of what the problem is.

Comment: Sounds like you can't get the escutcheon back off to get to the screws. You stick a tiny flat head into the slot and pop it off. ... Or there's a tab to get the knob off, so that you can pull the escutcheon off, but it's sunk behind the escutcheon now so you can't push it in to get the knob off. ... Uh. Have someone push on the other knob so you can get to the tab. ... You f'ed up putting it in, you might have to eff it up taking it out, and get a new one.

Comment: Can you pop the escutcheon to get to the tab on the knob? If not I'd sacrifice one of my lock picks getting it all bent up, sticking it in there flat and then turning it to get its bump to convince that tab to release.

Comment: @Mazura instead of including a random pic in the question, you should have just put the link in one of your 3 comments. It's very confusing up there.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44316/how-do-i-remove-this-doorknob - in those pics is what I mean by "pop the escutcheon" so you can get to the tab.

Comment: I've cropped & cleaned up the original image - but it still doesn't tell us much.